# What is going on in the system? How are the formulas $mg \sin(x)$ and $mg \cos(x)$ derived?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors

When a load is resting on an inclined plane, there is force $mg \sin(x)$ that's vertical to the inclined plane and force $mg \cos(x)$ horizontal to the plane acting on it like this:

[image]

My textbook says the weight $mg$    has two components: $mg \sin(x)$ and $mg \cos(x)$.

But when adding up $mg \sin(x)$ to $mg cos(x)$ it does not equal to  $mg$.

If `mg` and N are the only forces in this system,  which means the net force should be 0, how should I explain the existence of $mg 
\sin(x)$ and $mg \cos(x)$? Does $mg \sin(x)$ and $mg \cos(x)$ have their own reaction force to cancel them out and turn the net force to be 0 too or is it wrong the say the system's net force is 0?

And how are the formulas $mg \sin(x)$ and $mg \cos(x)$ that are used to describe these two forces derived?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $mg\cos x$ and $mg\sin x$ are orthogonal vectors, not colinear, and the norm of their sum is the Pythagorean sum. This kind of addition is pretty common in physics as well as in other places basic vector algebra shows up -- an elegant example is in statistics, where independent (orthogonal) random variables get added in a Pythagorean way, while multiple recordings of a variable get added up linearly.

The fact that we can do this is actually a very good indicator -- and part of the proof -- of the fact that physical forces are mathematical vectors, i.e. that it satisfies vector algebra. So the answer to the question is really an empirical one -- this is how forces get added, and can be mathematically explained as them being vectors.

Answer (score 2):

1) $mg \cos\theta$ and $mg \sin \theta$ are the magnitudes of these two orthogonal vectors. These do add up to a vector with magnitude $mg$. You should review vector addition and Pythagoras' theorem.

2) "mg and N are the only forces in this system, which means the net force should be 0." Both the statement and implication are false. Not only are these not the only forces (the picture labels a frictional force with the traditional lower case f), but even if they were that would in no way imply that the net force should be 0. Perhaps you're thinking of a block on flat ground, where the normal force of the ground on a block is equal and opposite to the weight $mg$ of the block and the net force is zero. However, the normal force is not the "reaction force" (to use your terminology) of the weight of the block, which it seems you're thinking. (Exercise: identity that reaction force). Rather, it is the "reaction force" to the push of the block down onto the ground. On a flat surface, the force of that push is equal in magnitude and direction to the block's weight $mg$. On an inclined surface, this isn't the case. Consider the extreme case of a block on a vertical wall. Here, the block does not push down onto the wall at all (because the wall isn't beneath it at all), and this force being 0, the normal force of the wall on the block is 0 as well. Get comfortable with the difference between these two extreme cases, then review inclined planes in your textbook.

3) "Does mg sin(x) and mg cos(x) have their own reaction force to cancel them out..." Every force has a reaction force; its just a question of identifying it. $mg \sin(\theta)$ and $mg \cos \theta$ are two components of the block's weight. Earlier I gave you the exercise of identifying what the "reaction force" to the weight $mg$ of the block is. To figure this out, you need to first identify A) the object causing the force and B) the object acted on by the force. In the case of the block's weight, or more explicitly the force of gravity on the block, the object A) causing the force is the Earth, and the object B) experiencing the force is the block itself. The reaction force to "A on B" is "B on A" with equal magnitude and opposite direction. That is, the earth is pulled up with a force $mg$. Since the earth is so massive, $M \gg m$, its acceleration (found with $Ma = mg$) is tiny, and this effect is completely ignorable in the context of this problem.

4) The only action force / reaction force pairs that are relevant to this problem are those between the block and the inclined plane. A force of A) the block on B) the plane comes with an equal but opposite force of B) the plane on A) the block. The picture labels both components of the force of B) the plane on the block A) - the normal force N and the frictional force f. These are equal and opposite to forces of the block on the plane.

5) These are derived by breaking up a vector into two orthogonal components. You should review vectors, vector components, and a little trigonometry.