# How can gravity have a horizontal component?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

[image]

$mg$ obviously has no horizontal component, but on resolving it into components it seems to have a horizontal component $mgcos\theta sin\theta$. I know I'm doing something wrong here. How is this possible?

Comment: You're doing the decomposition incorrectly. The component is not horizontal, it is parallel to the surface. (Its magnitude is also not given by $mg\cos\theta\sin\theta$, either.)

Comment: It would help to know how you got mg cosθ sinθ. Clearly those two vectors do not sum to the gravity vector. (See [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78762/what-is-going-on-in-the-system-how-are-the-formulas-mg-sinx-and-mg-cosx?rq=1))

Comment: Gravity in this scenario doesn't have a horizontal component.   You would be more interested in the force components tangential and perpendicular to the surface.  Also, the surface itself exerts equal reverse forces to keep the mass in place.  Of course, if the tangential forces don't cancel out, the mass starts sliding down the slope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gravity doesn't have a horizontal component. The component of gravity normal to the plane in your diagram can be said to have a horizontal component, sure (and a vertical component of magitude $mg\cos^{2}\theta$). But there is also a component of gravity parallel to the plane of magnitude $mg\sin{\theta}$. *That* component can be resolved into a vertical and horizontal component. And guess what, the horizontal component is of magnitude $mg\sin\theta\cos\theta$ in the opposite direction to the horizontal component you've drawn and exactly cancels it out. Meanwhile the vertical components of these normal and parallel components are $mg\cos^2\theta$ and $mg\sin^2\theta$, and adding them together you get $mg$. Not really a surprise.

All you've really done here is add in two cancelling fictional horizontal forces, ignored one of them, and then complained that gravity has suddenly acquired a net horizontal force.

Comment: If the horizontal component of $mgsin\theta$ is perfectly cancels out $mgsin\theta cos\theta$, why does this component cause the wedge to accelerate towards the right(assuming the floor is frictionless)

Comment: There is also the normal force acting between the block and the wedge, perpendicular to the surface. This acts in the direction of the $mg\cos\theta$ on the wedge (and opposite on the block). Also possibly friction between the block and wedge, acting parallel to the slope and up along it for the block, and down to the left on the wedge. It is the normal force that pushes the wedge to the right.

Comment: Isn't the reason the block too accelerates to the right with the wedge that the horizontal component of $mgcos\theta$ exceeds the horizontal component of the normal force resulting in a net rightwards force on the block?

Comment: If the above is true then wouldn't gravity be causing a net rightwords acceleration

Answer (score 1):

The whole point in components is that **when you add them, they *must* must give the original vector**.

The two components you've drawn *don't*. Their sum is *not* the original gravity vector.

Remember that components are supposed to follow coordinate axes, so they are perpendicular to each other (in that way they take care of distinct directions so we can treat them seperately) and then consider this line of thought:

- If you start with the $mg\cos \theta$ component then think in arrows and you can imagine how a perpendicular second component must be in order for the sum to become the original. It must be pointing down the incline.
- If you start with the $mg\cos\theta\sin\theta$ vector, then there is *no way in the world* that a second perpendicular component can be made so their result is the original vector. Of this reason, perpendicular components is an impossibility.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the component of gravity **parallel to the surface** as 'Horizontal component'.
Similarly, the tangential component is 'Vertical component'.

Thus, the problem/ deduction is very dependent on the surface / inclination of our experimental table.

[image: Lets suppose our setup is inclined by an angle θ]

Lets suppose our setup is inclined by an angle 'θ'. In the above figure, we see the 'horizontal component' to be *'gsinθ'*.
Just a little touch of trigonometry.

Now, I believe the problem of gravity having a forbidden 'horizontal component' arises when we're lazy to hold the body in an inclined position and let it fall to a stable flat surface.

Still nothing's changed for the body in this new position or configuration. The above relations for it's components still must hold true.

Let's see:

The perpendicular 'vertical' component should be *g cos θ = g cos0° = g*.

And, the parallel 'horizontal' component is *g sin θ = g sin 0 = 0*.

And these results are (I believe) true and observed day to day.

I see the main problem to be the understanding of the angle 'θ' we're taking. We look for it in the body while it is the plane we should be really focused on observing.
θ becomes 0° and thus invisible in the flat surface but it is as essential as the invisible air around around us to make sense of this problem.